# Where the value of one column is contained in the value of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to write a query which compares two tables and finds all entries where one field is contained in another field.  For example one field contains a single 5 digit login ID eg `12345`.  The second field contains one or multiple IDs seperated by commas but with the characters text^ in front eg `text^12345` or `text^12345,54321,13579,97531`

If I try

```
Select * from table1.login_id a
join table2.login_id b 
   on b.login_id LIKE '%' + a.login_id + '%'
```

I am finding is that it is only joining on the last entry in the list.  So if `a.login_id = 12345` it only brings back `where b.login_id = text^12345` or `text^54321,12345` but not `text^12345,54321`

Am I just missing something?

Note: I am using SQL Server 2008, so the query can't use CONCAT.

Comment: what db platform are you on?

Comment: Look into [CONTAINS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `CONCAT()` to assemble your string:

```
Select * from table1.login_id a
join table2.login_id b 
   on b.login_id LIKE CONCAT('%', a.login_id, '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a where exists is appropriate:

```
select * from table1 as a where exists (
    select b.login_id from table2 as b where a.login_id like concat('%', b.login_id, '%')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing something.  Your issue is not reproducible.

When I run the following:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (login_id varchar(255));
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (login_id varchar(255));

INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES ('12345');
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES ('text^12345,54321');

Select * from @Table1 a
join @Table2 b 
   on b.login_id LIKE '%' + a.login_id + '%';
```

I get:

```
login_id | login_id
12345    | text^12345,54321
```

So when you say

> it only brings back where b.login_id = text^12345 or text^54321,12345
>   but not text^12345,54321

You are wrong.  It does bring that text back.  Find the difference between the query you posted in your question, and the actual query you are using, and you will find what you are missing.  Or if there is no difference in the query, then the difference is in the data.  The data in your question may not be comparable to your actual data.